# Error with library iText when i made the install file

Tags: java, itext

I made a proyect in java using the library iText, when I install the program in other computer, the iText library not function.
I try to run the program in the IDE (netbeans) and function.
So the problem is in the momento to build the .jar.
Some one can help me?
thank you!

Comment: You claim *the iText library not function* but you don't tell us which error you get. I guess it's some kind of `ClassNotFoundException` that tells you that classes aren't found because you didn't add the correct jar files to the CLASSPATH. Or maybe you're trying to run iText 7 on a Java version predating Java 7. And what do you mean when you write *the momento to build the .jar*? This question isn't eligible for Stack Overflow, because you admit that iText works correctly (it functions in the IDE). You have a configuration problem, but you don't provide any info regarding the actual problem.

Comment: when I run it on netbeans dosen't throw error, but when I run in other computer after install it dosen't work, so I don't know where is the problem

Comment: And since you are the only one who knows what you did, and which error is thrown, *you* are the **only** person who can solve your problem *unless" you provide more information. Chances are that you have *a simple Java dependency problem* **that is totally unrelated to iText.**